# Solr Quickstart Tutorial: ERROR: Failed to create collection using command:

Tags: java, solr

[-name, gettingstarted, -shards, 2, -replicationFactor, 2, -confname, gettingstarted, -confdir, data_driven_schema_configs, -configsetsDir, /home/thompson/drive1/solr/solr-6.6.0/server/solr/configsets, -solrUrl, http://localhost:8983/solr]

I have the correct java: 
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

The version of Solr I have is 6.6.0

The location of the installation is non-standard:

/drive1/solr/solr-6.6.0

JAVA_Home is JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/src/jdk1.8.0

Ideas ??

If I go to localhost:8983 or 7574 I get a Solr dashboard named "Solr Admin"

Comment: In solr Admin check logging, what's the error its showing. ?

Comment: Two instance start up one at the previously listed port, and the 8983 time out trying to talk to the other.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the error "Failed to create collection" for the gettingstarted collection as well. I believe you can solve this by editing `bin/solr.in.sh` in your solr directory by updating `SOLR_HOST` as shown below.

```
SOLR_HOST="localhost"
```

Referencing where I found help: [Linked Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50119259/9499436)

P.s.
This will force solr to use localhost when it creates the collections. In my experience the root error was `SolrServerException:IOException` because although in the error the command says `-solrUrl, http://localhost:8983/solr`, solr had tried to use an IP when communicating with the solr server.