# solr tutorial fails to create collection

Tags: solr

I'm trying to run the solr 6.6.0 tutorial and after running:

```
bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt
```

it starts solr on ports 8983 and 7574 but fails to create the getting started collection with the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed to create collection 'gettingstarted' due to: {10.1.20.105:7574_solr=org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://10.1.20.105:7574/solr}


ERROR: Failed to create collection using command: [-name, gettingstarted, -shards, 2, -replicationFactor, 2, -confname, gettingstarted, -confdir, data_driven_schema_configs, -configsetsDir, /Users/rcarey/solr-6.6.0/server/solr/configsets, -solrUrl, http://localhost:8983/solr]
```

It looks like its trying to create each replica on a different ip, rather than a different port on the same ip. 10.1.20.105 is not the IP that the 8983 replica is using. I'm not sure if theres something additional I need to configure for this so that it uses the one IP for both. I have the host set to localhost.

The Solr Admin is available on both http://localhost:8983/solr and http://localhost:7574/solr

I get the following in the log:

```
24/08/2017, 11:38:36 ERROR null OverseerCollectionMessageHandler Error from shard: http://10.1.20.105:7574/solr

24/08/2017, 11:38:36 ERROR null OverseerCollectionMessageHandler Error from shard: http://10.1.20.105:7574/solr

org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://10.1.20.105:7574/solr
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:624)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:279)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:268)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1219)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler.lambda$submit$0(HttpShardHandler.java:163)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:176)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 10.1.20.105:7574 timed out
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:515)
... 12 more


24/08/2017, 11:38:36 ERROR null OverseerCollectionMessageHandler Cleaning up collection [gettingstarted].

24/08/2017, 11:39:06 ERROR null CollectionsHandler Timed out waiting for new collection's replicas to become ACTIVE with timeout=30
```

Help me to fix this.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. In `bin/solr.in.sh`, I uncommented and set the following:

```
SOLR_HOST="localhost"
```

Then things worked because solr communicated with the server via "localhost" instead of an IP, which had a timeout. Fixing the error:

```
SolrServerException:IOException occured when talking to server at: http://YOUR_IP/solr
```

Comment: Firewall rules may be to blame for this.